# Tar images, but not other files

Tags: php, tar

I have security camera, which uploads images to /security directory.
Once a day via cron job, I "zip" all images, and make one "tar" file for a day.
Tar files are located /security/archives.

I have the following in my server as a backup.php (located in "security" folder)
My problem with this script, it backups everything, including already created backup files.

How do I modify this script, so only thing that are inside those "tar" files are just current day images, no folders, no other files, just those images.
Thanks

```
<?php
$datestamp = date("Y-m-d");

// Current date to append to filename of backup file in format of YYYY-MM-DD

/* CONFIGURE THE FOLLOWING THREE VARIABLES TO MATCH YOUR SETUP */

$directory_path = "/home/myserver/public_html/security";

$dump_file_name = "/home/myserver/public_html/security/archives/Images-$datestamp.tgz";

$command = "tar -zcvf {$dump_file_name} {$directory_path}";

$result = exec($command,$output);

foreach(glob('/home/myserver/public_html/security/*.jpg') as $file){

   unlink($file);

}

?>
```

Comment: I quess I need to add --exclude path/to/images/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother, but got this working by changing:
$command = "tar -zcvf {$dump_file_name} --exclude /home/myserver/public_html/security/archives {$directory_path}";